Hostel booking cancellation a Czech 1 year visa
Been reading multiple forums and spoke to couple of people. Confused with the mixed reviews I got.
I have been granted a 1 year multi-entry visa by Czech.
I have a hostel booking from booking.com. However, my friends are also joining me from other parts of Europe and we want to get a private room or an AirBnB instead.
Tomorrow is the last date of cancellation and I am confused whether to cancel the booking which was used for the visa application and proceed with another booking .
On what instances are they revoking the visa?

Is this the first time you use that visa?

Yes. My entry and exit would remain the same. No changes in that. Except the hostel bit

I have had other Schengen visas previously with Germany and Hungary. But I never had issues when I cancelled the booking and rebooked a cheaper option or something . But Czech seems to be tricky. First hand information - my frnds cancelled their bookings and nothing happened.

There have been a few stories on this site about Schengen visas being revoked because an original hotel booking was cancelled. The only example I can find in a hurry was about a Slovenian visa, but I am pretty sure there have been (perhaps only comments) telling about similar issues in other Schengen states as well. The legality is based on interpretation. There is no specific requirement in the regulations that you have to follow a pre-described itinerary, on the other hand, if you do not, it is also not too far fetched for immigration authorities to consider it deception.

It’s really confusing tbh. The grey area.

Play it safe ans use the reservation.
